# How to count total character occurence in data frame and add column using mutate in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame (`dat`) with a column having sequence (`Seq`) (character class). I am trying to split the sequence in each row and count the numbers of `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'`, `'T'` and add each column using mutate (in `dplyr`). Below is my sample data frame and code I am trying.

```
   Seq
CAGGACATAA
TGTCCACTGC
```

Code I am trying to execute:

```
count_bases <- function (x){
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
        tab[i] <- table(strsplit((x)[i],""))
    }
    return(tab)
}
count_bases(dat$Seq)
```

If I just use for first row the command: `table(strsplit(dat$Seq[1],""))` it works fine and gives me the result. Desired output which I am trying to get is by above function and mutate to create a data frame shown below:

```
    Seq    A C G T
CAGGACATAA 5 2 2 1
TGTCCACTGC 1 4 2 3
```

Comment: Something like `do.call(rbind, lapply(dat$Seq, function(x){table(strsplit(as.character(x),""))}))`?

Comment: what about `cbind(dat,t(apply(dat, 1 , function(x) table(strsplit(x,"")))))` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the above code with "do.call" and got this warning "Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 54)" am I doing something not correct? Also can this function be called to add these columns to existing data frame (dat). Thanks again

Comment: Oh, that might happen if one of your sequences doesn't have every base. You could rewrite the function to avoid that, but it'd start to get complicated...there's probably a simpler way. To collect into a data.frame, use `data.frame(dat, ... )`.

Comment: You can relevel the factor so you get zeros where you should: `data.frame(dat, do.call(rbind, lapply(dat$Seq, function(x){table(factor(strsplit(as.character(x),"")[[1]], levels = c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')))})))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using dplyr with tidyr, which would handle any number of sequences of any length/composition:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(Seq = c("CAGGACATAA", "TGTCCACTGC"), 
                                      stringsAsFactors = F)

result <- dat %>% 
            # explode each seq into indvidiual 
            # characters on individual rows
            mutate(seq.split = strsplit(Seq, "")) %>%
            unnest() %>%  
            # count by each type of character in eah Seq
            group_by(Seq, seq.split) %>%
            summarise(n=n()) %>% 
            # convert to wide table format
            spread(seq.split, n)

result
Source: local data frame [2 x 5]

         Seq     A     C     G     T
       (chr) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1 CAGGACATAA     5     2     2     1
2 TGTCCACTGC     1     4     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of big, but you can use `strsplit` to split, and then `lapply` across the results to build a list of tables (or split within the `lapply` function; whichever you prefer). You can then recombine the list with `do.call(rbind`, and add it to the existing data.frame with `data.frame`. You need to use `as.character` to convert any factors to string, and `factor` to make sure any empty levels get added by `table`.

```
dat <- data.frame(Seq = c("ACGACCGGG", "CAGGACATAA", "TGTCCACTGC"))

data.frame(dat, do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(dat$Seq), ''), function(x){
    table(factor(x, levels = c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')))
})))
#          Seq A C G T
# 1  ACGACCGGG 2 3 4 0
# 2 CAGGACATAA 5 2 2 1
# 3 TGTCCACTGC 1 4 2 3
```